# Abstracting a List<T> whose source may be recursive via an interface in C#?

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I am creating a little utility that grabs an image from wherever I want it from ( web, filesystem, ftp, etc. ) and do some processing on it. For the main loop that works through the list of files to process, I want the source of my image objects to be abstracted so that the primary processing routine doesn't care where it comes from. For example my

I was thinking of creating an interface, roughly like so

```
  interface IBitmapStreamProvider {

      List<Bitmap> FileQueue;
      bool SaveOutput(Bitmap filetosave);

}
```

Then I can keep it simple and do

```
foreach(Bitmap bmp in fileSystemBMP.FileQueue)
{
   BitmapProcessor.DoStuff(bmp);
   fileSystemBMP.SaveOutput(bmp);
}
```

That way I have a class that can provide a list, the saving is abstracted, and so is the source.

This would be simple if I was just creating a simple List from a single location, say a directory with no subdirectories. But how do I design this List or call it, if it's a recursive location? I want the code to open one bitmap at a time, and constantly update the list of work until it's exhausted. Also if it's a web pull or ftp pull, that file would be pulled on demand one at a time. But I want the iteration to be the trigger for doing that.

I don't want the implementation to worry about the source, just do it's work and loop on a List object. On the same token, opening everything at once is not an option, prepopulating the list of files isn't good either since it could be theoretically huge list. It basically needs to happen one file at a time. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Change `FileQueue` to `IEnumerable<Bitmap>`. For a recursive source, you can use LINQ or recursion to generate a `List<Bitmap>`. For your web service scenario (or if you're working with a huge list of files), use `yield return` to load your Bitmaps lazily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement lazy loading of bitmaps using `yield return`. To do so `FileQueue` should be of type `IEnumerable<Bitmap>`. For a recursive list, use LINQ or recursion to create a flattened list of files (or paths)...

```
interface IBitmapStreamProvider 
{
    IEnumerable<Bitmap> FileQueue;
    bool SaveOutput(Bitmap filetosave);
}

public class BitmapStreamProvider : IBitmapStreamProvider
{    
    public IEnumerable<Bitmap> FileQueue
    {
        get
        {
            return GetNextFile();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Bitmap> GetNextFile ()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fileLocations = // load list of file uri's or paths here, recursively if needed
        foreach (var location in fileLocations)
        {
            var bitmap = // fetch bitmap
            yield return bitmap;
        }
    }

    public bool SaveOutput(Bitmap filetosave)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, and I've already wired up a proof of concept and am off and running. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that instead of using a List for your FileQueue that you may wish to instead use an IEnumerable. Then you can create a class that implements IEnumerable for each interface type (web, filesystem, ftp, etc.) that will properly generate the list. The result of this is that you will only pull each file when you iterate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your interface:

```
bool NoMoreData {get; set;}
```

And change your loop to a while:

```
while (!fileSystemBMP.NoMoreData)
{
   Bitmap bmp = fileSystemBMP.First();
   BitmapProcessor.DoStuff(bmp);
   fileSystemBMP.SaveOutput(bmp);
   fileSystemBMP.Remove(bmp);
}
```

There are a lot of ways to get the next item, I provided one in the sample above. You could also change to a Queue and just use Dequeue (this would be a bit cleaner). Because your processing could finish before the list is fully populated, a foreach isn't going to work here.

Of course the implementation of IBitmapStreamProvider would need to set "NoMoreData" when it was done getting files.

You could also change to an IEnumerable and use yield return as Anthony Chu suggested. That will do effectively the same thing as above (the foreach won't terminate until the function with the yield return actually finishes). This has the advantage of not needing to change your foreach code.